# gsub not working for a string - clues into what could be wrong

Tags: r, gsub

I'm having a scenario as below:

```
    > print(bob)
    [1] "Do not fall in love if you can’t handle pain"
```

When I try to replace the can't with gsub, it does not work:

```
    > gsub("can't", "can not", bob)
    [1] "Do not fall in love if you can’t handle pain"
```

Yet if I simply replace the object with its content, it works fine:

```
    > gsub("can't", "can not", "Do not fall in love if you can't handle pain")
    [1] "Do not fall in love if you can not handle pain"
```

I'm really baffled as I can't think of any difference between these two that would be causing it to fail:

```
    > summary(bob); summary("Do not fall in love if you can't handle pain")
    Length     Class      Mode 
    1        character character 
    Length     Class      Mode 
    1        character character
```

The variable bob was derived from a dataframe, such that:

```
    bob <- dataframe$column[3]
```

So my only lead is that it may have something to do with the dataframe.

The same thing happens with str_replace. Please let me know if you have any insights as to what may be causing this.

Comment: `gsub("can’t", "can not", bob)`. There's a difference between `’` and `'`.

Comment: Okay that is bizarre. If I copy and paste your code it works... But how do I get that symbol? There's only one option on my keyboard.

Comment: I've got no idea - try googling, there's surely a way your keyboard can get you there.

Comment: As others have mentioned already the apostrophe is likely a different character than you think.  Try `gsub("can.t", "can not", bob)`  Here dot matches any character.

Comment: Oh I see I can use alt+0146. Never in my life have I faced this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some helpful commentators pointed out that the symbols are not matching.
The correct symbol can be typed by holding alt+0146.
Otherwise, using "can.t" in the gsub function will match any symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[[:punct:]]` to match any punctuation:

```
gsub("can[[:punct:]]t", "can not", bob)
# [1] "Do not fall in love if you can not handle pain"
```